# Are there any known MD5 collisions for two plain-text ascii strings (not binary data)

Tags: hash, md5, checksum, hash-collision

There's many MD5 collision examples out there on the web, but as far as I can find, they all involve binary data inputs.

Are there any two known plain-text ASCII strings that give the same MD5 hash?

Basically I'm building a de-duplication system that stores plain text files such as JSON + XML, but it skips over any files that are detected to contain binary data.  And I need a way to test how the system copes with two plain text (non-binary) files/strings that give the same MD5 hash.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason you're using MD5 rather than a more secure hash function like SHA-256?

Comment: @templatetypedef 

Yes. Initially I was actually doing that (combo of CRC32+MD5+SHA512).  

But changed to simply using MD5 for few reasons: (1) Using postgres with efficient `UUID` type as primary/foreign-keys.  (2) Lots of other systems already generate MD5s for files. (3) Simplicity. (4) Performance.  

The combination of these benefits have been great since I made the change.  

The system is programmed to simply reject 2nd+ colliding files, which is an acceptable compromise in my use case considering the upsides. I just need a way to test my rejection code using plain text inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I share a sample that was posted to Twitter!

> md5("TEXTCOLLBYfGiJUETHQ4hAcKSMd5zYpgqf1YRDhkmxHkhPWptrkoyz28wnI9V0aHeAuaKnak")
> =
> md5("TEXTCOLLBYfGiJUETHQ4hEcKSMd5zYpgqf1YRDhkmxHkhPWptrkoyz28wnI9V0aHeAuaKnak")
> https://twitter.com/realhashbreaker/status/1770161965006008570